# HTTP/2 on windows server 2016 not enabled

Tags: http, iis, iis-10

I [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis) that server 2016 IIS 10 support HTTP/2 by default.
I have several IIS servers with win server 2016 (1607) OS, IIS 10.0.14393.0
when I check the site protocol in dev tools, it shows HTTP/1.1
checked: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` 
there are no DWORD values:
`EnableHttp2Tls ,  EnableHttp2Cleartext`

what am I missing here?

Comment: Have you walked through the demo? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis#iis-with-http2-demo-walkthrough

Comment: Yes, I did all these configurations.

Comment: Are you still getting HTTP/1.1 even when you use anonymous authentication for an empty https website? Have you ever tried IISreset or reboot server?

Comment: Of course, iisreset, reboot, etc. These servers are running for more then a year

Comment: I remembered in some case, HTTP/2 will be displayed as mutiple concurrent http/1.1 requests in developer tools but the web browser is using http/2 indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some digging, it appears that the culprit is our f5/big-ip version 13 which does not support HTTP/2 server-side traffic. 
so all traffic falls back to HTTP/1 when reaching our LB. upgrade f5 to version 14.1.0 minimum in order to support HTTP/2 server-side traffic. 
https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K04412053

thanks all for replying.